# LDAP authentication apache 2.2

Tags: authentication, ldap, apache-2.2, mod-auth-ldap

I am trying to install basic ldap authentication on a website on an apache 2.2 server. I put this in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

```
LoadModule ldap_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
```

I located those modules, so i am sure they exsist.

I put this in my /etc/apache2/sites-avaible/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName monitoring.site.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/Monitoring/public

        <Directory /var/www/Monitoring/public>
         AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthType Basic
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthName "Monitoring"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc1.site.local:389/DC=site,DC=local?sAmaccountName?sub.(objClass=*)"NONE#
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Admin,CN=Users,DC=site,DC=local"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword secret
        require valid-user
....
```

But when i try to restart my server i get this error

> Syntax error on line 23 of
>   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
>   Invalid command 'AuthBasicProvider',
>   perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server
>   configuration Action 'configtest'
>   failed. The Apache error log may have
>   more information.    ...fail!

I tried to enable some modules with a2enmod with no succes.
My apache server: Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Did you try to change the order of the lines ``AuthType`` and ``AuthBasicProvider``?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) `AuthBasicProvider` directive is provided by `mod_auth_basic`. You should check if this module is enabled in your configuration by running `apache2 -M`

Comment: yes this worked in my case. thanks